# How to detect the last 2 words using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi sorry for the simple question but how can I detect the last two words in the String?

Let say I have this var:

```
var sample = "Hello World my first website";
```

How can I get the last two words dynamical. I tried the split().pop but only the last word is getting

```
var testing = sample.split(" ").pop();
console.log(testing)
```

Comment: Why not simply use `pop` twice?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just try with:

```
var testing = sample.split(" ").splice(-2);
```

`-2` takes two elements from the end of the given array.

Comment: then `.join(" ")` to return a string.

Comment: No need to use splice as it gives an array in return again. Just `var t =sample.split(" ");
var testing = t[t.length -1];
var testing2 = t[t.length -2];`.

Comment: Better use `slice` instead of `splice` - you don't want to mutate the original array

Comment: @Bergi Why not? The original array is temporary and inaccessible after the line is executed. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JaredGoguen One more reason not to do anything with it. Of course it doesn't make a difference, but then my best practice is to default to `slice`.

Comment: @JaredGoguen doesn't `splice` delete all elements from the beginning, whereas `slice` only copies the last 2 ?

Answer (score 8):

Note that splice again give an array and to access the strings again the you need to use the index which is same as accessing directly from splitted array. Which is simply

```
var words =sample.split(" ");
var lastStr = words[words.length -1];
var lastButStr = words[words.length -2];
```

---

If you prefer the way you are doing. you are almost there. Pop() it again.

> The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.

```js
var sample = "Hello World my first website";
var words= sample.split(" ");
var lastStr = words.pop(); // removed the last.
var lastButStr= words.pop();
console.log(lastStr,lastButStr);
```

Note , pop() removes the element. And make sure you have enough words.

Comment: @VLR No problem. Hope you enjoy my answer. I really do not care about downvote if it doesn't have a comment.

Comment: Although this answers the question, it would nice to see some better names for those variables

Comment: @StefanMihaiStanescu Absolutely correct. Haven't noticed. Now it looks better I guess :D

Answer (score 3):

Or do it with a regex if you want it as a single string

```js
var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain";
var res = str.match(/[^ ]* [^ ]*$/g);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Tongue in cheek: fixing a problem with Regex means you now have 2 problems: the original problem and the Regex you need to maintain and properly document.

Comment: As @jacques marais answer points out, I'd probably avoid splitting on space to retrieve words. `('how; now. brown cow?').split(' ')` => `["how;", "now.", "brown", "cow?"]` vs alphanumeric `('how; now. brown cow?').match(/\w+/g)` => `["how", "now", "brown", "cow"]`. Of course, this has it's own issues, like unicode special characters (e.g. ☃) so this will need to be adjusted per actual use ...

Answer (score 1):

```js
var splitted = "Hello World my first website".split(" ");
var testing = splitted.splice(splitted.length - 2);
console.log(testing[0] + " " + testing[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```js
var sample = "Hello World my first website";

var testing = sample.split(" ").slice(-2);
console.log(testing)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like:

```
sample.match(/\w+\W+\w+$/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var testing = sample.split(" ").splice(-2).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

First we have to split the string using split function,then by using splice we can get last two words and concatenate those two words by using join function.

please check this

```
sample.split(" ").splice(-2).join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved in several ways. the one I prefer is the following that splits the problem in sub problem:

1. transoform a sentence in an array
2. get last 2 items of an array

### Transform a sentence in an array

```
let sentence = "Server Total Memory Capacity is: 16502288 MB";
let sentenceAsArray = sentence.split(' ');
```

### Get last items of an array

```
let numberOfItems = 2;
let lastTwo = sentenceAsArray.splice(-numberOfItems)
```

### Join array items

At the beginning we transformed a sentence into an array. Now we have to do the complementary operation: transform an array into a sentece.

```
let merged = lastTwo.join(' ')
```

### Print into console

Now that we have new variable with desired content, can show it printing variable into the console with the following command.

```
console.log(merged)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr function

```
var sample = "Hello World my first website";
var testing = sample.substr(sample.length -2);
```

Answer (score -1):

1. `sample.split(' ').slice(-2);`
2. `sample.split(' ').splice(-2);`
3. `sample.split(' ').reverse().map((x,i) => i < 2 ? x : '').filter(x => x !== '');`